# Simple riddle to play

Tags: riddle

1. I am the weakest among my friends
2. You can't live a single day without me on earth
3. I put things together
4. I won't let you go away from me. But you can
5. You can't see me but you can feel
6. Millions of years passed nobody knows who, why, how, exactly I am
7. But I am what I am

Answer (score 16, accepted):

May be answer is

> gravity

Explanation -

> 1. Gravity is the weakest force among all the forces 
>  2. Gravity is the thing which pull things together   
>  3. As there is a gravity on the earth we can’t live without it  
>  4. As there two famous attempts to understand gravity (Newton,Einstein) but both couldn’t crack it ,yes Einstein did solve but failed to explain it in quantum level